# Reference to database and/or server name in is not supported in this version of sql server

Tags: java, android, sql, azure, jtds

I try use SQL command:

```
SELECT *
FROM [demo].[SalesLT].[Address]
```

in my Azure database http://vrcorpdatabase.database.windows.net  from my app. It is worked in Visual Studio on .Net platform. I try use this SQL command in Android Studio and I have got error

> Reference to database and/or server name in is not supported in this
>   version of Sql Server.

What problem is possible here?

Comment: You question is not  in pure English. I cannot understand it.

Comment: Post your code. So that we can understand which is causing the issue

Answer (score 1):

I did it. Microsoft Azure SQL does not support connectivity with Android. I created a Microsoft SQL Enterprise virtual machine in Azure, and my application works well.